# Cant access variable inside of firebase gotData() function outside

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the value of power_level value on the last line of the below mentioned code but it is not showing anything. I need that value for further use what to do.

```
var config = {
    //
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("power");
ref.on("value", gotData, errData);

var power_level;

function gotData(data) {
    var power = data.val();
    // Grab the keys to iterate over the object
    var keys = Object.keys(power);
    console.log(keys);
    for (var i = keys.length - 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        // Look at each fruit object!
        var power_level = power[key];
        console.log(power_level);
    }
}
console.log(power_level);
```

Comment: console.log is firing before gotData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't get the value on the last line is because it is asynchronous. Basically you do `ref.on` and it runs the `gotData()` function if (and more importantly WHEN) it is successful, but your last `console.log()` runs regardless of whether `gotData()` is finished.

An easy way to handle this is by defining a separate function which takes power_level as a parameter and handles the power_level, and run that at the end of `gotData()`.

Something like this:

```
var config = {
//
 };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("power");
ref.on("value", gotData, errData);

var power_level;
function gotData(data) {
var power = data.val();
// Grab the keys to iterate over the object
var keys = Object.keys(power);
console.log(keys);
for (var i = keys.length-1; i < keys.length; i++) {
var key = keys[i];
// Look at each fruit object!
var power_level = power[key];
console.log(power_level);

////////// call handlePowerlevel here to handle logic further
handlePowerlevel(power_level)
}
}

function handlePowerlevel(pl) {
  console.log(pl);
  // actual logic
}
```